# Different screen orientation for iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation, landscape, portrait

I need to create portrait only orientation for iPhone and landscape only for iPad. What is smartest way to archive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xcode tab "General"->Deploy Info->Device Orientation, check the right option.